# Validity of analysis of summation of function of primes using Abel–Plana summation:

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the analytic function $g(x)$

Define

$$f(x)=g(x)\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(x)}{2x}\right)}{\cos^2\left(\frac{π}{2x}\right)}$$

Note that:

$$f(p)=g(p) \text{ for prime } p$$

And $f(n)=0$ for non-prime integer $n$

Now set $g(x)$ Such that

$$|f(x+it)|=o(e^{2πt})$$

uniformly for every $x$ (Necessary condition for the use of finite version of  Abel–Plana summation as in [Olver's book "Asymptotics and special functions"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://books.google.com/books/about/Asymptotics_and_Special_Functions.html%3Fid%3D-UBZDwAAQBAJ%26source%3Dkp_book_description&ved=2ahUKEwimyoLysPznAhV_4XMBHdxIDi8QmhMwBnoECA8QIw&usg=AOvVaw0c-orqzOtWgH8jDMAW85ZI))

Also we can see

$$\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(x+it)}{2(x+it)}\right)}{\cos^2\left(\frac{π}{2(x+it)}\right)}=o(1)$$ uniformly for every $x.$

Now for application of Abel–Plana (infinite version) one more condition is necessary:

$$-i\int_0^\infty\mathrm dt \, \frac{f(x + \mathrm it) − f(x −\mathrm it)}{\mathrm e^{2πy}-1}=o(1)$$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Or more strongly

$$|f(z)|<\frac{C}{|z|^{1+\varepsilon}}$$ for any $\varepsilon$ and $C$

Now we can see that

$$\sum_{k=5}^\infty g(k) =\sum_{k=5}^\infty f(k)=\frac{f(5)}2 + \int_5^\infty f(x) \, dx + i\int_0^∞\frac{f(5+iy) − f(5−iy)}{e^{2πy }− 1} \, dy 
$$

i.e. here we can calculate explicit constants/values for infinite sum of function of prime but $g(x)$ with above properties is very very rapidly decaying ;so not of apparent use I think.

> Question : I want to ask if the above analysis is correct or not? I have doubts because :I saw somewhere even if convergence is assured of both sides( in our case first two conditions) the Poisson summation fails and Abel–Plana is very similar to Poisson summation.

Comment: Generally, any formula for primes or prime-counting functions that utilizes the gamma function $\Gamma(x)$ isn't considered to be very useful.

Comment: @StevenClark please see the point of analysis. I know it's not good for estimate but see the direction of argument.

Comment: Assuming $h(x)=\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi\, \Gamma(x)}{2\, x}\right)}{\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2\, x}\right)}$ and noting for example that $|h(5+i)|\approx 101363$ and $|h(6+i)|\approx 1.03172\times 10^{24}$, I'm wondering what function $g(x)$ can be used to satisfy $-i\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{f(a+i t)−f(a−i t)}{e^{2 \pi t}-1}\, dt=o(1)$ as $a\to\infty$ or more strongly $|f(z)|<\frac{C}{|z|^{1+\varepsilon}}$ for any $C$ and $\varepsilon$ where $f(x)=g(x)\, h(x)$. I assume the stronger condition applies to $z\in\mathbb{C}$ versus only to $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @StevenClark that's what I'm concerned about! I think g(x) could be such that it counters the wild behaviour  of h(x).